# While loop showing only one record when i use nested while loop for fetch data from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have case manager table where i have inserted court table id as foreign key. i want to fetch record from both tables. when using nested while loop it shows only one row data.

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$query1 = "SELECT * from `case_manager` where user_id = '$id' ";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, "$query1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $Status = $row['status'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    $case_type = $row['case_type'];
    $court_id = $row['court_id'];
    $query2 = "SELECT * from `case_type` where case_id = '$case_type'";
    if($result1 = mysqli_query($conn, "$query2")) {
        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            echo $row2['case_name'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah first results get over written by the second. You need to use `JOIN` in your query and both tables need to have relationship. Does your tables have a common ID or a relationship if so will be easy to help you.

Comment: Because you are overwriting the variable `$result1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are overwritting you `$result1` change inner query result to `$result2` then try

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$query1 ="SELECT * from `case_manager` where user_id = '$id' "; 
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn , "$query1");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1 ,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $Status=$row['status'];
  $id = $row['id'];
  $case_type = $row['case_type'];
  $court_id = $row['court_id'];
  $query2 ="SELECT * from `case_type` where case_id = '$case_type'"; 
  if($result2 = mysqli_query($conn , "$query2")){;
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2 ,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      echo $row2['case_name'];
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help i have use join `SELECT case_manager.id, case_manager.client_contact_number,case_manager.client_email,case_manager.client_name, case_manager.billing_type, case_manager.created_on, case_manager.updated_on, case_manager.status , case_type.case_id , case_type.case_name , court.court_id , court.court_name FROM `case_manager` INNER JOIN case_type ON case_type.case_id = case_manager.case_type INNER JOIN court ON court.court_id = case_manager.court_id WHERE user_id = 40`

Answer (score 1):

**1st :** Because you are overwriting the variable **$result1** In second query execution.

```
if($result1 = mysqli_query($conn , "$query2")){;
   ^^^^^^^^                                   ^^
```

**Note :** And remove that unnecessary semicolon .

**2nd :** No need multiple query simple use join

```
SELECT cm.*,c.* from `case_manager` cm 
join `case_type` c  
on cm.cas_type=c.case_id 
where cm.user_id=$id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query to fetch your record:

```
$query = SELECT case_manager.* ,case_type.case_name FROM case_manager Left JOIN case_type ON case_manager.case_type=case_type.case_id where case_manger.user_id = $id;

While($row = mysql_fetch_array()){
  echo $row['case_name'];
}
```